# How to burn visible image/text on data side of CD-R

Tags: compact-disc

This may be a very strange question.

I noticed that a burned CD-R and an empty CD-R is different if you watch the recording surface carefully. Now I want to burn some words (visible to human but not CD drives) on the disk. So I tried to use a marker to write something on the CD-R (recording surface) and burn it in a CD-R drive. But unfortunately, the burning process failed as soon as the laser hit the written word on the disk. Is there any method for me to force the software and drive burn the CD-R ignoring any error?

Thank you very much!

NEW FINDINGS:

Some drives have such functions, namely LabelFlash or DiskT@2 etc. But these technologies all require special CD-R drives which I don't have. Is there any way to realize such technology with software methods?

I also find someone did this several years ago:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Burning-visible-images-onto-CD-Rs-with-data-beta/?ALLSTEPS

But the project is still in prelimilary state, and the author didn't update it afterwards. Are there any more mature and feasible methods?

Comment: do you actually want to use the CD-R for anything afterwards?

Comment: I don't quite get it. What is the point of writing something if it should not be readable afterwards? Why do you write at all?

Comment: Actually I want to write something readable in the inner area of the disk. And I want to burn some human visible words on the useless outer area. Is it possible?

Comment: I vaguely remember there was a tool that created a file specifically to get words on a CD R. Can't remember what it was called tho ;p

Comment: Are you looking to affectingly just write words on the CD surface (and therefore not readable by a CD player)? If so, does it have to be done via a CD burner?

Comment: Yes, I just want to write visible words on unused recording surface of CD. It doesn't have to be done via a CD burner, but will a focused sunlight work?

Comment: It's technically possible, some Yamaha burners had this feature some years ago. Haven't heard about it for ages.

Comment: I understand you want the other side of the disc affected, but just FYI ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightscribe

Comment: No, not the label side, but the data side.

Comment: Interesting requirement, nice idea!